# Angular 13 and NPM module with moment.js

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I have date-picker module for Angular wherein I importing moment.js. Actually I importing NPM package moment-es6 which importing moment.js like this:

```
  import * as moment from "moment";
  export default moment;
```

That same issue I have if I import moment.js by my self in my module like this

```
  import * as moment from "moment";
```

On Angular 12 it works without any issue. But on Angular 13 when I am trying to use moment.js in this module I got error because moment.js is not imported properly

> moment_es6__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

This issue occurs only when I build module as PROD

My tsconfigs:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declarationMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.lib.prod.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this. I tried few things but no success

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it turns out that using this import fixes similar problems

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

I also found this tricky import:

```
import * as temp from 'moment';
const moment = temp["default"];
```

Did you tryed these imports?

Comment: I Tried both: 
First option works if you add in project where you use this package in tsconfig `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

Second: Works but you can't type field like this `date: moment`, you have do this like that `date: tmp`.

It's solving problem but I have to choose which way I want to go

Comment: Finally I chose first options because it's cleaner and `ng build` informing precisely what we have to do to make it works (adding `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`). I sure I'll get question few times why it's no longer working bacuse they will not read error message, but it's better solution I thing, thanks for help :)